# Most appropriate way to display CPT's by children terms of custom taxonomies while retaining desired permalink structure?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, templates

I'm currently building a small store section on a site of mine with the use of CPT's & Custom Tax's for the first time. So far I've successfully got my CPT's & Tax's working as expected however since this is my first time I'm still a bit stumped about the best approach to take to present this content via templates???

#### Things to note to better understand my goal-

• The store items are all using **(1) CPT** called "**Store Items**"
• The store is going to contain products that fall into a few different custom tax's, eg. 
**Product Categories** - w/ children such as (Clothing, Accessories, CDs) filed under that custom tax. / **Brands** - w/ children such as (Brand 1, Brand 2, etc.) filed under that custom tax, and lastly something like **Artists** - w/ children such as (Artist 1, Artist 2, etc.) filed under that custom tax.

#### I'd like my URL structure to be easy to understand and follow according to what product, etc. is selected, so -

• When your visiting the store itself it will just be - www.mysite.com/store 
• When your visiting a product in the store, I'd like it to be something like - www.mysite.com/store/clothing/mens/t-shirts 
(the thing to note here is that "clothing", "mens", and "t-shirts" are children terms added to my custom taxonomy called "Product Categories") - This is the part I'm hung up on and not sure how to go about...

It's just my assumption that the current approach I've devised with 1 CPT along with my custom tax's is the best way to achieve my goal, so even if the core of how I've approached this is in your opinion haltering my goal then I'd love to know what you think.

Thanks for the help! 
Best, 
SB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what appears to be the solution I needed after a lot of digging so I figured if anyone else might need the example, here it is...
http://mondaybynoon.com/2011/05/20/revisiting-custom-post-types-taxonomies-permalinks-slugs/